# TFS and one-up releases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-sourcesafe, version-control-migration

I apologize for the length of this post but I needed to include a lot of information for proper answers. I hope this does not discourage responses...

Our shop historically has coded web sites using Classic ASP with some newer ASP.NET sites configured as web sites. As everyone knows this means that the source files (*.asp, *.aspx, **and** *.aspx.vb (or *.aspx.cs)) files are deployed to development and production servers as is.

The configuration management process was (and still is) entirely manual and includes the following steps (requirements):

- Taking copies of the modified files and storing them in a "release" folder for archiving.
- Taking copies of the production files that will be replaced and storing them in a "archive" folder for easier rollback.
- Generating a diff report of before and after source files for code review or general reference when diagnosing a post-release issue.
- The developer who coded the changes is not the person who performs the production release. The original developer is required to hand off the **source** files to another developer for some additional testing and production deployment.

To make the situation more difficult (not with the above..but with what I talk about below) we do not follow a formal release schedule. As **individual** bugs or enhancements are completed they are released. This means we could easily be making several releases to a site a week. It is even possible that a given site gets two different releases to **individual** pages on the same day!

Since I came on board I have been trying to transition the team to newer technologies like ASP.NET web applications and ASP.NET MVC. (We have also taken on responsibility for stand-alone applications and console utilities used for non-web processes...so my dilemma still applies.)

The difference between these technologies and the legacy technologies is the pre-compiling. Instead of deploying the code-behind files (*.aspx.vb (or *.aspx.cs)) a dll or exe gets deployed. This type of deployment package has raised several questions (issues ??).

- Generating difference reports when the source has been compiled. While the newly modified source files are sitting on the developers system the production copy is a compiled copy.
- Making sure that changes related to other bugs or enhancements are not included in the particular release. This would apply to both the original developer and the person performing the release.
- Allowing the original developer to pass along the changed files to another developer for build, testing, and deployment.

Up to now I was the **only** developer on the team working on these types of sites and applications so the conflicts and issues mentioned above where non-existent. (I skip the difference report step and the I do my own deployments.) However, I am trying to push the rest of the team to embrace this plus allow for better distribution of bugs and enhancement tasks.

We are currently using VSS but I am pushing (and will most likely succeed) in getting us moved over to TFS. Some ideas I have are

- Setting up a separate build system for use by the developer to do the deployment. This will solve two problems -- (1) Different versions/patches of Visual Studio and other libraries between developers and (2) instances where the person performing the release has checked out files locally for another change. (Of course this does not guarantee differences between the build system and the original developer but at least that means the release is from a consistent config.
- Using labels to tag just the modified files. My problem is that while I can identify (and pull down for a build) the modified files, how do I identify the files that need to be included in the build but have **not** changed. Again, the idea is to not included checked in files that are related to un-released changes.
- Using labels to tag all the files for the release (the modified files and the unchanged files). My problem with this is similar to the last one...how do I make sure that a file checked in by another developer (say they went on vacation) for an un-related change is not labelled and included in this build.
- Using the labels I could probably write a script to generate difference reports for the labeled version and the previously labeled version. If the process works properly that **should** result in **exactly** what changes are included in the the particular release..?

Any other ideas, concerns, points of interest? While I do have some flexibility of the process some of the requirements (like difference report or some way to easily view differences and having separate developer/deployer) are most likely untouchable.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of different versions of the code and to help you manage very fast release cycles (daily) vs long term enhancements you can use branches in TFS.

There is a ton of information out there on branching, but in general I like to try to keep things simple. For example, have one branch called "release" and another "development". Everybody works on the development branch but the code to be deployed to production is merged into the release branch right before release.

This blog post describes the process:

http://team-foundation-server.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-we-branch-our-code-in-tfs.html

Comment: We would just need to maintain discipline that two developers do not merge into release at the same time. (Unless we **wanted** to push two changes at the same time.) Correct?

Comment: Let me read up on your link and a bit more on branching concepts before I mark any answers. While I knew about branching (never used it though) I did not think of it for my dilemma. Do you foresee labeling still playing a part? Maybe just for identifying change sets (correct term??) or does the SP integration with bugs and tasks cover that? It was my understanding that I can configure the environment to require check-outs (or check-ins) to be associated with an assigned bug or task.

Comment: I don't use labels as much now that we use branches, but there are times where we do label inside a branch. You'll have to see what works for you.

Comment: I would suggest you keep the migration to TFS simple. It's tempting to replace too many things (e.g. tools and processes) too soon, too fast and scare the team off. In my experience the migration to TFS for source control is easy...changing the way people work (e.g. now we are going to use this new bug tracking system and new workflow) is much harder. You might want to do it in phases.

Comment: Been reading up on branching and merging. Does this scenario sound like it will work. Maintain a MAIN branch that developers branch off of for each change they work on. (Devs never check out from MAIN...just the DEV branch.) When rdy for release they take the DEV branch and merge it back to MAIN. The MAIN branch is then branched to a specific RELEASE branch that is marked as read-only. The only spot for conflict would be if two devs merged back into MAIN at the same time (unless that was expected).

Comment: For what is worth, I've put together this blog post to describe the way I do branching: http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Simple-Branching-Strategies-for-Team-Foundation-Server

Comment: Doesn't this create additional overhead of testing the build once changes from DEV stream were merged to MAIN stream? Basically dont you end up testing 2 streams? Wouldn't it be easier to just create a snapshot branch from DEV stream upon release once it's been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on my experience with VS2003 vs VS2010 for example is that the project structures are different and allowing VS to do a conversion often times results in a solution that either requires a lot of refactoring or is unusable. Having said that; if you can transition everything over to TFS2010 then one way to handle it is to setup different projects for each solution and use the TFS built in version handling for the different releases. You can also set up a build server and schedule nightly builds. If the build is ok then you can push this version into testing and ultimately production. You should really read up on TFS because it's totally different from VSS and is definitely a huge upgrade in allowing you to do team-focused development.

P.S. TFS has a really good Sharepoint integration which will help you and your team keep track of all the bugs and tasks.

Comment: Yeah. We currently use disconnected (from source control) SharePoint lists to manage our bugs, enhancements, and lists but I have read up on the SP integration. The idea of tying a source control check-in to a specific bug or tasks would definitely help.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the TFS versioning enough to say how/if that will help. I have thought about doing nightly builds and in the long run that may actually be more stable instead of intra-day releases. Will need to read up more on that.

Comment: Yes, doing nightly builds ensures that people check in only working code into TFS. Also, you can assigned specific bugs/tasks to specific users. When they check in their code, they can associate the code with any number of bug fixes/tasks that the code addresses. This way you can run reports to see how individuals are performing and what kind of tasks they completed. Check this out for some information directly form the horse's mouth: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/4acefd21-725d-4107-ba9c-bdfa8fe54012/